# jquery anchor detect & prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within an anchor, this works:

```
$(this).prepend('<span>This is the span content</span>');
```

when trying to do if href equal to, it does not work

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').prepend('<span>You have selected Google</span>');
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup for the anchor tag?

Comment: have you verified that $('a[href="http://www.google.com"]') actually returns an element?

Comment: $('a').each(function() {

Comment: var url = this.href; // this works gets the url

Comment: @bocca, be sure to note that `$(this).attr('href')` returns just what is visible in the markup, and `this.href` will return a full `Location` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done a sample one and didn't find any error.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#btn1").click ( function() {
        $("a[href='http://www.google.com']").prepend ( "<span>You have selected Google</span>" );
    });
});
</script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>
<button id="btn1">Click me</button>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/igowi)**

Answer (score 1):

If you have this HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Then your selector will work:

```
$('a[href="http://www.google.com"]').prepend('<span>You have selected Google</span>');
```

If you wanted to follow the strict escaping guidelines on the jQuery website, then it would look like this:

```
$('a[href="http\\:\\/\\/www\\.google\\.com"]').prepend('<span>You have selected Google</span>');
```

I suspect, you are possibly wanting something like this which applies the concept in an `if` statement, in a `click` event:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    var $a = $(this);
    if($a.is('[href="http://www.google.com"]')){
       $a.prepend('<span>You have selected Google</span>');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Try the following HTML, for me in Firefox 3.5.6 on a Mac it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('a[href="http://www.google.com/"]').prepend("<p>Hello!</p>");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
        <a href="nowhereyouvebeen">No where you've been</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Perhaps you have a trailing slash in one url but not the other: "http://www.google.com/" vs. "http://www.google.com"? The two have to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with amp and & symbols